# Using Jasmine in multiple JS files, avoiding db race conditions

Tags: javascript, jasmine, web-api-testing

We've got a medium sized API that we're testing with Jasmine. Right now we just have one gigantic file though.

I'd love to split the tests out into individual files, but my understanding is that the tests will not necessarily run sequentially, and therefore introduce all kinds of inconsistency with the underlying database.

Is there a good model to follow for organizing tests across multiple files in a way that will ensure a predictable dataset when each test runs?

Answer (score 0):

Configure Jasmine to run your tests sequentially instead of semi-randomly by setting `"random": false` in `spec/support/jasmine.json`.

See [this setup doc](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html) for more info.

Comment: So can I be confident that no two tests will be running simultaneously? (For example, a test that retrieves a user's comments may fail incorrectly if being run at the same time as a test that deletes the user.)

Comment: Please see [this page](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async) of the Jasmine docs for information about how Jasmine will wait for each test to complete (and if the test is an asyncfunction, for the promise to resolve) before moving on to the next